# How to override the back button behaviour in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a provider that I want to reset upon using the **back button to go to the previous screen**, so I would like to **manually edit the code of the back button's Navigator**. Where is this code located?

One solution would be to add a back button in the app bar, but the Android back button will still do its own process and I will miss the code necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found this, worked for me: https://flutteragency.com/how-to-execute-when-clicking-back-button-in-flutter/

1. Wrap the `Scaffold` widget with a `WillPopScope` widget and let `Scaffold` be its child.
2. Give the **onWillPop** property to `WillPopScope` and make sure you do two things:

```
Navigator.pop(context, false);
return Future.value(false);
```

The return is important, the other pop you can edit or do whatever you need before this return statement.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/31834289)

Comment: Sorry, I will edit this and provide the answer from it. (Update: Edited)

Answer (score 1):

You can handle back button navigation by using  WillPopScope widget.

In this widget you can handle it in onWillPop method.

Example

```
@override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return new WillPopScope(
          child: new Scaffold(
            appBar: new AppBar(
              title: new Text('Page 2'),
            ),
            body: new Center(
              child: new Text('PAGE 2'),
            ),
          ),
          onWillPop: () async {
            return false;
          },
        );
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the back button by using it as an Icon

```
leading: IconButton(
  onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
  icon: BackButtonIcon(),
  color: Colors.deepOrange
),
```